# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /profile

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I have created the user profile model. I migrated the model to syn with the database. However I am getting an error of `User has no profile` when I route to `/profile (whose url is this url(r'^profile$', views.update_profile, name="profile"),)` which should call the `update_profile` view where I have printed the `request` object before checking if its a POST method or not but it is also not shown in shell. Where have I done wrong?

Here is my code

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=600, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)


def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)


def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
post_save.connect(save_user_profile, sender=User)


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')


class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        exclude = ('user', )


def update_profile(request):
    print('user ################', request.user, request.user.profile)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(
            request.POST or None, instance=request.user.profile)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(
                request, ('your profile was successfully updated!'))
            return redirect('products:profile')
        else:
            messages.error(
                request, ('There was an error updating your profile'))
    else:
        user_form = UserForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    return render(request, 'dashboard/company/profile.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form})
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I found the result just after posting the question. If i need to delete the question, I will sure delete it otherwise here is the solution for this

```
def update_profile(request):
    try:
        profile = request.user.profile
    except Profile.DoesNotExist:
        profile = Profile(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(
            request.POST or None, instance=profile)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(
                request, ('your profile was successfully updated!'))
            return redirect('products:profile')
        else:
            messages.error(
                request, ('There was an error updating your profile'))
    else:
        user_form = UserForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    return render(request, 'dashboard/company/profile.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form})
```

the updated part in the above code is

```
try:
        profile = request.user.profile
    except Profile.DoesNotExist:
        profile = Profile(user=request.user)
```

I cannot explain clearly but looking at the error, RelatedObjectDoesNotexist at profile gave me an idea to check if the request.user.profile exist or not so I tried this way and it worked for me. Feel free to explain in detail, if anyone knows about this well.

Answer (score 0):

You could write that in somewhat lesser code like,

```
def update_profile(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(
            request.POST or None, instance=profile)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(
                request, ('your profile was successfully updated!'))
            return redirect('products:profile')
        else:
            messages.error(
                request, ('There was an error updating your profile'))
    else:
        user_form = UserForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)
    return render(request, 'dashboard/company/profile.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form})
```